# localhost, Microsoft SQL and php

Tags: php, sql-server-express

I just started learning PHP and MySQL, and I got stuck when trying to connect to my database from a PHP block. I have installed XAMPP and SQL Server Express 2012 on my machine. My server name is RAFAL-MAC and I selected 'Windows Authentication.'

I have a simple HTML page with PHP code in a file called search.php

the PHP code is

```
<?php
    $con = mysql_connect('RAFAL-MAC','RAFAL-MAC\Rafal','');
    if (!$con)
    {
        die( 'Could not connect: ' . mysql_error() ) ;
    }
    mysql_select_db("one", $con) or die(mysql_error());
?>
```

When I go to localhost:8080/search.php I get the following warning:

**Warning:** mysql_connect(): Host 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server in C:\xampp\htdocs\search_submit.php on line 11
Could not connect: Host 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server

I tried searching similar problems online, but all of the threads are about remote connections. I am just trying to connect to my local SQL server.

Any hints? I apologize for any missing information. Thanks! :)

EDIT:
I changed the server name to 'localhost'

Now I am getting this:

*Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'one'*

Comment: Technically, it's a remote server, not a local one (running on your machine). The advice about remote servers will apply to this scenario as well. If you're on *one and the same machine* with all this, use `localhost` as the server address

Comment: If you are just learning, you should not be using `mysql_*` functions they are deprecated.  Perhaps use `mysqli` or `PDO` instead.

Comment: It's too bad they're deprecated... pain to change everything

Comment: wait, whaaat? :O I'm using the online tutorials. hmm... I should look up tutorials for SQL 2012?

Comment: Google mysqli - newer version

Comment: I answered your question - you need to specify a user with a login, not ''

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you'd like to connect to **SQL Server Express 2012**, all functions beginning with mysql* will fail - since these functions speak to **MySQL servers**.

Please install Microsoft's [MS SQL Server driver pack](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20098) found [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20098). From this page:

> Perform the following steps to download and install the Microsoft
>   **Drivers for PHP for SQL Server**:
>
> 1. Download SQLSRV30.EXE to a temporary directory
> 2. Run SQLSRV30.EXE
> 3. When prompted, enter the path to the PHP extensions directory
> 4. After extracting the files, read the Installation section of the SQLSRV30_Readme.htm file for next steps

People in [Microsoft's PHP driver forum](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqldriverforphp/threads) should easily be able to answer your question, in case you still have problems after the installation of the driver.

Additionally, if connecting to the local machine, try to use these addresses:

- localhost
- 127.0.0.1

These two addresses always **reference the local machine**.

Comment: SteAp is correct, Microsoft SQL Server and mysql are entirely different databases. Also if for any reason you want to use mssql_* functions as opposed to PDO, you will need to install FreeTDS drivers. That's the only way I've ever got PHP talking to MS SQL.

Comment: Do I just extract the .dll's to my C:\xampp\php\ext folder? I'm not sure what to do with those files.